# Pomegranate for hidden markov models in python

Tags: python, dataset

I want to use hidden Markov model for classification on a dataset that I have been using with pomegranate library in python. I read the documentation but I'm confused about how to make the Hmm for the dataset . Can anyone suggest me a proper  method on how I can do it with pomegranate? Also how should the dataset format should be?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

From hmm tutorial on [pomegranate site](http://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HiddenMarkovModel.html), i don't see 'classification is mentioned, in that case you must implement your own 'classification' libraries. But you can still 'make' hmm. This is called 'training' or 'fitting'.  But i guest u can't 'classify' using pomegranate.

'Dataset' or 'feature' model is wisely dependent on your case, for example in speech recognition (which is 'classification' also), an MFCC feature is 39 independent mixture gaussian per single hmm observation.